# Collecting all feathers and glyphs in Assassins Creed 2

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I've completed the main Assassins Creed 2 story and now am trying to get to 100% synched. I can see all the other stuff on the map, but how can I find all the feathers and glyphs?

I don't really want to cheat too much! (i.e. use a walkthrough guide) - so is there something I'm missing in the game itself which would help me locate them? Or is it just a case of wandering around randomnly until they all turn up?

Comment: To be honest, I would not bother with the feathers. The only thing standing between me and 100% sync was one lousy stinking feather and it took me hours to find. When I did, all I got a brief cut scene and a cape. Waste of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using walkthroughs:

- For the feathers, yes, you need to wander around until you find them.
- For the glyphs, check out the enciclopedia, the locations with an eye (red, as that means you haven't found it yet) contain a glyph, search around main buildings for it. They are not that hard to find (and the movie revealed is very interesting)

As others have said, and you probably know, using eagle vision is easier to spot feathers (and mandatory to activate Glyphs)

Answer (score 3):

The Locations menu will show you which buildings have a glyph on them. As for feathers, it's just a matter of searching.

It is much easier to find the glyphs on the buildings, and the feathers, if you use your eagle vision.

Answer (score 2):

A good tip on finding feathers is to wander on top of the buildings and activate your Eagle Eye!!! Everything becomes darker and the feathers will look white with little sparks glowing on top of them.

On the other hand, Glyphs are commonly hidden on high places. As @Macha said earlyer, The Locations menu will show you the buildings that contain Glyphs on them.

Answer (score 0):

For the feathers:

- Double check your world map.  They'll appear on there.  I'm not sure if you actually need to see them, or if it's sufficient to get the lookout points.  If you have trouble finding them due to it being overcrowded, remember that you can filter it.
- Look at your additional memories.  In the additional memories section, you'll see which districts still have features
- If you still can't find them, check the art merchants.  I've seen them a map of where all the features are.

For the Glyphs:

- Use the locations database and sort/filter by Subject 16.
- Make sure you use Eagle Vision when you're look for them, and favor looking high
- Don't forget to look inside buildings.

Comment: I think you are merging Assassin's Creed II and Assassin's Creed Brotherhood.